# How to get TV info from Google Calendar Event?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'm using the Google Calendar API to retrieve events for each of my favorite sports teams.  An example calendar can be found [here](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/htmlembed?src=nhl_23_%2557ashington%2B%2543apitals%23sports%40group.v.calendar.google.com&ctz=America%2FNew_York).

When you click on an event, it will show you information about the game, including the TV network it'll be played on, like this:

[image: Event detail example]

I'm making a home automation script to automatically detect events and turn on my TV etc., and change to the correct channel.  My problem is that when I make a call to the API, the response doesn't include the TV information, each item looks like this:

```
{
   "kind": "calendar#event",
   "etag": "\"3014707204000000\"",
   "id": "20171021T233000_2017102123",
   "status": "confirmed",
   "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=MjAxNzEwMjFUMjMzMDAwXzIwMTcxMDIxMjMgbmhsXzIzXyU1N2FzaGluZ3RvbislNDNhcGl0YWxzI3Nwb3J0c0B2",
   "created": "2017-06-22T20:49:57.000Z",
   "updated": "2017-10-07T05:20:02.000Z",
   "summary": "Panthers @ Capitals",
   "creator": {
    "email": "nhl_23_%57ashington+%43apitals#sports@group.v.calendar.google.com",
    "displayName": "Washington Capitals",
    "self": true
   },
   "organizer": {
    "email": "nhl_23_%57ashington+%43apitals#sports@group.v.calendar.google.com",
    "displayName": "Washington Capitals",
    "self": true
   },
   "start": {
    "dateTime": "2017-10-21T19:30:00-04:00"
   },
   "end": {
    "dateTime": "2017-10-21T22:30:00-04:00"
   },
   "transparency": "transparent",
   "visibility": "public",
   "iCalUID": "20171021T233000_2017102123@google.com",
   "sequence": 0,
   "gadget": {
    "iconLink": "https://calendar.google.com/googlecalendar/images/sport_hockey.png"
   }
  }
```

Does anyone know where this information is stored or if it's retrievable?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you can after getting that json reply download the "htmlLink" and parse the line that says TV:

It would be something like this(pseudo code):

1. Get JSON
2. Execute something like `curl htmlLinkValue | awk '/TV:/' > result.txt`
3. Read that file that will contain the networks.

Regards